# angular-ui-tinymce, data-mce-bogus="1" on model

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui, tinymce-4

I've encountered a weird behavior in ui-tinymce, would appreciate your help.

I implement ui-tinymce and the editor works great, except that tinymce's default element appears on the modal if no value was inserted to the editor.

```
$rootScope.tinymceConfig  = {
    inline: false,
    resize: false,
    valid_elements : "a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align|dir],br,ul,ol,li,hr,p[dir],span[dir]",
    toolbar: "bold italic underline | link image | bullist numlist | alignleft aligncenter alignright | ltr rtl | removeformat code",
    plugins: "autolink link image directionality paste code",
    paste_as_text: true,
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
    paste_remove_spans: true,
    paste_remove_styles: true,
    paste_retain_style_properties: false,
    skin: 'lightgray',
    menubar: false
  };

<textarea rows="10" class="form-control"
                              ui-tinymce="tinymceConfig"
                              ng-model="someModal"></textarea>
```

The model value (when the editor is empty) is set to be:

```
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
```

If I understand correctly, this code block is a root element pushed by tinymce in case that the editor is empty in-order to enable mouse clicks on the editor.. it shouldn't appear in the model.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the model value you've assigned to the element is not valid HTML, null, or an empty string. It's horribly annoying, and even setting it often times TinyMCE will still set the $form as $dirty, but that's another issue altogether.

To fix, try initializing your model value (someModal in your example) to an empty paragraph:

```
$scope.someModal = $scope.someModal ? $scope.someModal : "<p></p>";
```

That's valid HTML and TinyMCE won't set that Bogus flag, just set it in your controller. I used the Ternary operator there since I assume this is part of a CRUD interface and you're likely to be loading existing data as well as inserting new. This is the quickest fix I've used if you just want it to leave your data alone when it's blank (or new/insert)

HTH!